# Problem with Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: android

I have rooted my device, then in my application

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

and it work fine, my application will be root mode. Then I try add wlan address space, but it doesn't work, when I check out in terminal, following error message is shown

```
 busybox ifconfig there is not a new wlan address space.
```

I try with following way:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("busybox ifconfig wlan0 add xxxxxxxxxxxx");
p.waitfor();
```

When I run my application, the toast shows that the app is root mode but there is not added wlan0.

Comment: Of course, if I write in terminal su, busybox ifconfig wlan0 add xxxxxxxx, it's works fine and there is a new wlan0 address space.

Answer (score 1):

The "su -c COMMAND" syntax is not really supported. For better portability, use something like this:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
stream = p.getOutputStream();
stream.write("busybox ifconfig wlan0 add xxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

The write() command doesn't exists as-is, but I'm sure you'll find how to write your stream to it, maybe encapsulating the output stream in a BufferedOutputWriter or so.

Answer (score 1):

because the process that started with "busybox" is not the same one
which started with "su". you should like this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
dos.writeBytes("busybox ifconfig wlan0 add xxxxxxxxxxxx" + "\n");
dos.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

That might be because when you run `su`, it launches one process. Then you run `busybox ...`, and it happens in another process, which is not started as a superuser.

Try something like

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "busybox ifconfig wlan0 add xxxxxxxxxxxx"});
```

, i.e. executing it in a single command-line.

Comment: sorry, It dosen't works! no more toast that app is superuser and no wlan address space added.

Comment: @user760503: oh sorry, i forgot the `-c` switch. It should look like this: `exec("su -c \"busybox ifconfig wlan0 add xxxxxxxxxxxx\"")`

Comment: @user760503: `man su` tells that the syntax is `su -c COMMAND`.

Comment: yes,I noticed after reading man pages. but it doen't work. I have tried out following way:

Comment: exec("su -c \"busybox ifconfig wlan0 add xxxxxxxxxxxx\"") dosen't work and and following works only sudo part: String[] cmd = {"su","-c","busybox","ifconfig wlan0 add xxxxx"} sudo works now but no wlan has been added!

Comment: in terminal su -c "busybox ifconfig wlan0 add xxxxxx" works, but how can I do it in an one process in java part?

Comment: just one question more. Now I

Comment: This is tested solutions. String[] cmd = {"su","-c","busybox ifconfig wlan0 add xxxxxxx"}; Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); process.waitfor(); and some try catch after that.  Thanks for help!